# Oracle SQL NTILE Over Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to split a data set into multiple sets of N-TILES but am unsure whether my current method is the best way to go about it
So essentially I want to go from this

```
  col1   col2  col3
   x1     3     5
   x2    13     4
   x3     3     5
   x4     5     7
   x5     1     8
   x6     1     12
   x7     5     11
   x8     3     23
```

to

```
  col1   col2  col3  nt1    nt2
   x7     5     11    1       1
   x4     5     7     1       1
   x3     4     5     1       2
   x2     13    4     1       2
   x8     3     23    2       1
   x6     1     12    2       1
   x5     1     8     2       2
   x1     3     5     2       2
```

I'm currently using a with clause to

```
 ntile(2) OVER (ORDER BY col2 DESC) nt1
```

then partitioning over that

```
ntile(2) OVER (PARTITION BY nt1 ORDER BY col3 DESC) nt2
```

However with lot's of rows this is fairly slow so I was wondering if there's a more efficient or just more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Your expected results don't seem to agree with your `ORDER BY col2 DESC` clause.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp They do seem consistent. `nt1` has the higher 50% in the 1st n-tile (since the order is `DESC`) and the lower 50% in the 2nd n-tile. `nt2` is based on `nt1` (not `col2`) and `col3` and has a similar assignment to the n-tiles.

Comment: Would `NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY col2 DESC, col3 DESC)` not do the trick for you? If you used the same order by in your ntile(2) functions, you'd get the same splits. This may or may not be what you're after, however...

Comment: @Boniest, No that wouldn't work I tried that. I need it split by the first condition and then those splits to be split by the second condition.

Comment: @JoeLaw is the issue that the ntile(4) spits out values 1 - 4, and you're after groups that are 1 or 2, and sub groups that are 1 or 2? Because if so, that's just a couple of case statements - i.e. `case when ntile(4) over (...) in (1, 2) then 1 else 2 end`, `case when ntile(4) over (...) in (1, 3) then 1 else 2 end`. Otherwise, I think you're stuck with your current approach. You may find some improvements by having an index on all the columns being used in the query, although this will only really be of use if your query uses a small subset of the table columns.